# How to remove the username/hostname line from an output on Korn Shell?

Tags: ksh, aix

I run the command

```
df -gP /data1 /data2 | grep -v File | awk '{print $1}' |
    awk -F/dev/ '$0=$2' | tr '\n' '
```

on the AIX shell (ksh) and it prints the output below:

```
lv_data01 lv_data02 root@testhost:/
```

However, I would like the output to be printed this way. Could someone help?

```
lv_data01 lv_data02
```

Comment: Append this to your command: `; echo`

Comment: you have an unmatched single quote as the last char of your posted code. Either add a matching (you probably want `' '` (with a space in there) ) , or you should delete it (probably causing a different error). You need to learn to debug such problems yourself. First look at the output of your first two cmds : `df -gP /data1 /data2 | grep -v File`, then add on each segment to understand where your code  is failing. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep … | awk … | awk …` is not necessary; a single `awk` could do the whole job. So could `sed` and it might even be easier.  I'd be tempted to deal with the spacing by using:

```
x=$(df … | sed …); echo $x
```

The `tr` command, once corrected, replaces newlines with spaces, so the prompt follows without a newline before it.  The `; echo` suggestion adds the missing newline; the `echo $x` suggestion (note no double quotes) does too.

As for the `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/File/!{ s/[[:space:]].*//; s%^.*/dev/%%p; }'
```

- Don't print anything by default
- If the line doesn't match `File` (doing the work of `grep -v`):

  - remove the first space (blank or tab) and everything after it (doing the work of `awk '{print $1}'`)
  - replace everything up to `/dev/` with nothing and print (doing the work of `awk -F/dev/ '{$0=$2}'`)
- The command substitution and capture, followed by `echo`, deals with spaces and newlines.

So, my suggested solution is:

```
x=$(df -gP /data1 /data2 | sed -n '/File/!{ s/[[:space:]].*//; s%^.*/dev/%%p; }'); echo $x
```

You could add `unset x` after the `echo` if you are going to be using this directly in the shell and not in a shell script.  If it'll be encapsulated in a shell script, you don't have to worry about it.

I'm blithely assuming the output from `df -gP` won't contain a path such as this, with two occurrences of `/dev`:

```
/who/knows/dev/lv_data01/dev/bin
```

If that's a real problem, you can fix the `sed` script, but I don't think it will be.  It's one thing the second `awk` script in the question handles differently.